# Angular10 - Safari error: "The provided animation property 'offset' is not a supported CSS property for animations

Tags: angular, safari, offset, angular-animations

I'm using @angular/animations, but when i use the property "offset" in order to make a stagger effect, in Safari blocks the execution of the entire website. After having removed it, it start running correctly again.

This is my piece of animation:

```
const staggerOpacTrans =    [
transition('* => *', [
  query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),

  query(':enter', stagger('100ms', [
    animate('.5s ease-in-out', keyframes([
      style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(20px)', offset: 0 }),
      style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1 }),
    ]))]), { optional: true })
]),]

export const staggerOpacTransAnimation = trigger('staggerOpacTransAnimation', staggerOpacTrans);
```

I've tried installing this polyfill: **'web-animations-js'** and importing it in polyfills.ts, but still it doesn't work.

Has anyone ever had problems with **offset** property animation browsing with Safari?
All the other browser supports that feature perfectly.

Thank you[image: This is the error it throws]